# Creating JDBCRealm with postgres driver

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, tomcat7, jdbcrealm, server.xml

So I'm trying to create a JDBCRealm for my application instead of using the users from tomcat-users.xml.

Ive changed my server.xml to look like this :

```
   <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/> -->


    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
             debug="99"
             driverName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
             connctionURL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MyDataBase"
             connectionName="xxxxxxxx"
             ConnectionPassword="xxxxxxxx"
             userTable="authUsers" userNameCol="name" userCredCol="password"
             userRoleTable="authRole" roleNameCol="role" />
  </Realm>
```

so - UserDatabaseRealm is commented out, and instead I put in my JDBCRealm element.

but for some reason I keep getting a nullPointerException when I start my tomcat,
originating in the postgres driver class :

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Realm[JDBCRealm]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.startInternal(CombinedRealm.java:201)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.startInternal(LockOutRealm.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1109)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.open(JDBCRealm.java:710)
at org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm.startInternal(JDBCRealm.java:788)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 17 more
```

I use tomcat 7 with postgres 9.3 and the jar I use for the driver is postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc4.jar.

any ideas why it won't work? any known bugs with this driver? or is it something in my element?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like Tomcat is passing `null` JDBC URL to me.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is frightfully simple:

```
connctionURL="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MyDataBase"
```

Spot the typo in the parameter name.

Since you did not provide a `connectionURL` parameter, the driver cannot properly initialize, hence the exception.

Comment: Quite. Questions like these tend to be flagged for removal and here we have a featured one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<JDBCRealm"
debug="99" driverName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver" 
connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/authority?            
user=test;password=test" userTable="users"
userNameCol="user_name"
userCredCol="user_pass"
userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role_name" />
```

refer below link for more explanation...

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/JDBCRealm-howto.html